# How can i display all InfoWindow for markers when load the map

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

When load google map i need to display all infowindow alongside with marker
How can i do this ? 
below is the code that display infowindow when click marker 
Thanks

```html
<html>
  <head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
  <script>
    google.charts.load('upcoming', { 'packages': ['map'] });
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawMap);

    function drawMap() {
      var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Country', 'Population'],
        ['China', 'China: 1,363,800,000'],
        ['India', 'India: 1,242,620,000'],
        ['US', 'US: 317,842,000'],
        ['Indonesia', 'Indonesia: 247,424,598'],
        ['Brazil', 'Brazil: 201,032,714']           
      ]);

    var options = {
      showTooltip: true,
      showInfoWindow: true
    };

    var map = new google.visualization.Map(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

    map.draw(data, options);
  };
  </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="chart_div"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```